# making a live sketcher via webcam using openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to make a live sketcher using openCV module but the cv2.imshow function is showing error.I have attached the screenshot of the error.
Kindly help..

```
import cv2
def sketch(img):
   img_gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   img_gray_blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray,(5,5),0)
   canny_edges=cv2.Canny(img_gray_blur,10,70)
   ret,mask=cv2.threshold(canny_edges,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
   return mask
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
   ret,frame=cap.read()
   cv2.imshow('live sketcher',sketch(frame))
   if cv2.waitKey():
       break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of error. Kindly see it.

Comment: before imshow you should check that img is not null and len(img.shape)==3 or ==4

Comment: Yes,it's showing the length of image as 3..what should I do?

Comment: 'def sketch(img):  if img is not None: print("image is present") print(len(img.shape))'

Comment: The code runs when I restart my jupyter notebook, but on running the second time, shows error..can anyone explain the reason for this..?

Comment: probably because it is never reach the cap.release(). Check it first.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your loop is iterating once and that's because of this

```
if cv2.waitKey():
    break
```

change this to

```
if cv2.waitKey(1)==13: #13 is the enter Key
    break
```

you are closing the window after first frame ..
Hope this helps